# Mimic "LaTeX font arrow" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Is it possible to make TikZ identify the LaTeX font used in the current document and (say through defining a proper "mimic style") make it automatically draw arrows with the "same" shape?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,fourier}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\draw [->] (0,0) -- (1,0);}
$\rightarrow$
\end{document}
```

How can the Ti*k*Z arrow be made to match, just given the current font configuration?

[image: mismatch]

Comment: It does not seem clear to me what you mean by "mimetize" (mimic?) the same shape.

Comment: @strpeter I mean "looking as close as possible".

Comment: So can you give a visualized example? I simply do not get your point.

Comment: The shape of an arrow (say \rightarrow) depends on the font used, I would like TikZ to recognize this font, and adapt its arrows accordingly.

Comment: This needs a massive amount of effort if you want *all* fonts.

Comment: OK, this make sense. Then, what about some (the most usual) of them? Is there anything done in this direction?

Comment: LaTeX uses specialized math fonts for \rightarrow, of which there are very few (see tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).  I'm not sure where XeLaTeX gets its math symbols.

Comment: If the arrowhead part is available, then it is relatively easy to put that head in a node, comparing to redrawing it.

Comment: @suitangi: To me it is still unclear what arrow you want to mimic.

Comment: @strpeter I don't want to mimic any particular arrow. I wanted to mimic the arrow style (head, tips,...) corresponding to the used LaTeX font.

Comment: @suitangi: There are tons of arrows. Look at [the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). So can you at least say which font style you are aiming for? Because like it is now this question is too broad!

Comment: @strpeter Yes, I understand this. However I thought (maybe wrongly?) that the style could be summarized much more briefly (for example, the standard heads are always the same, etc.).

Comment: @strpeter By the way, my current target font is eulervm.

Comment: Please reopen this question. This is a documented feature of [tag:tikz-cd] called **glyph arrow tips**.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, see [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd)'s manual for more information

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,fourier}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    fourier to/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow]},
    fourier notowns/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=notowns]},
}

\tikz[line width=.53pt]\draw[fourier notowns-fourier to](0,0)to[bend right](1,0);

\end{document}
```

[image]